# What is imported with spark.implicits._?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is imported with `import spark.implicits._`? Does "implicits" refer to some package? If so, why could I not find it in the Scala Api documentation on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scala allows you to import "dynamically" things into scope. You can also do something like that:

```
final case class Greeting(hi: String)

def greet(greeting: Greeting): Unit = {
  import greeting._ // everything in greeting is now available in scope
  println(hi)
}
```

The `SparkSession` instance carries along some implicits that you import in your scope with that `import` statement. The most important thing that you get are the `Encoder`s necessary for a lot of operations on `DataFrame`s and `Dataset`s. It also brings into the scope the `StringContext` necessary for you to use the `$"column_name"` notation.

The `implicits` member is an instance of `SQLImplicits`, whose source code (for version 2.3.1) you can view [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala).

Answer (score 6):

It's scala's feature to import through object, so the api documentation did not describe about it. From Apache spark source code, `implicits` is an object class inside `SparkSession` class. The `implicits` class has extended the `SQLImplicits` like this :
`object implicits extends org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits with scala.Serializable`. The `SQLImplicits` provides some more functionalities like:

1. Convert scala object to dataset. (By toDS)
2. Convert scala object to dataframe. (By toDF)
3. Convert "$name" into Column.

By importing `implicits` through `import spark.implicits._` where `spark` is a `SparkSession` type object, the functionalities are imported implicitly.

Comment: can you do this in java? `import SparkSession.implicits$;`