# How import spark.sqlContext.implicits._ works in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, extension-methods, implicit

I'm new in Scala

Here's what I'm trying to understand

This code snippet gives me RDD[Int], not give option to use `toDF`

```
var input = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

But when I import `import spark.sqlContext.implicits._`, it gives me an option to use `toDF`

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
var input = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)).toDF
```

So I looked into the source code, `implicits` is present in `SQLContext` class as `object`. I'm not able to understand, how come `RDD` instance is able to call `toDF` after import ?

Can anyone help me to understand ?

update

found below code snippet in SQLContext class

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala

```
  object implicits extends SQLImplicits with Serializable {
    protected override def _sqlContext: SQLContext = self
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toDF` is an extension method. With the import you bring necessary implicits to the scope.

For example `Int` doesn't have method `foo`

```
1.foo() // doesn't compile
```

But if you define an extension method and import implicit

```
object implicits {
  implicit class IntOps(i: Int) {
    def foo() = println("foo")
  }
}

import implicits._
1.foo() // compiles
```

The compiler transforms `1.foo()` into `new IntOps(1).foo()`.

Similarly,

```
object implicits extends SQLImplicits ...

abstract class SQLImplicits ... {
  ...

  implicit def rddToDatasetHolder[T : Encoder](rdd: RDD[T]): DatasetHolder[T] = {
    DatasetHolder(_sqlContext.createDataset(rdd))
  }

  implicit def localSeqToDatasetHolder[T : Encoder](s: Seq[T]): DatasetHolder[T] = {
    DatasetHolder(_sqlContext.createDataset(s))
  }
}

case class DatasetHolder[T] private[sql](private val ds: Dataset[T]) {

  def toDS(): Dataset[T] = ds

  def toDF(): DataFrame = ds.toDF()

  def toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame = ds.toDF(colNames : _*)
}
```

`import spark.sqlContext.implicits._` transforms `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)).toDF` into `rddToDatasetHolder(spark.sparkContext.parallelize...).toDF` i.e. `DatasetHolder(_sqlContext.createDataset(spark.sparkContext.parallelize...)).toDF`.

You can read about implicits, extension methods in Scala

[Understanding implicit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375633/understanding-implicit-in-scala)

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

[Understand Scala Implicit classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844327/understand-scala-implicit-classes)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-extension-methods.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html

[How extend a class is diff from implicit class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033008/how-extend-a-class-is-diff-from-implicit-class)

---

About `spark.implicits._`

[Importing spark.implicits._ in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151189/importing-spark-implicits-in-scala)

[What is imported with spark.implicits._?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878224/what-is-imported-with-spark-implicits)

[import implicit conversions without instance of SparkSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984326/import-implicit-conversions-without-instance-of-sparksession)

[Workaround for importing spark implicits everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724290/workaround-for-importing-spark-implicits-everywhere)

[Why is spark.implicits._ is embedded just before converting any rdd to ds and not as regular imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197905/why-is-spark-implicits-is-embedded-just-before-converting-any-rdd-to-ds-and-no)

Comment: before implicit its a RDD instance, so after import implicits._, Does all methods including toDF of implicits added to RDD's instance ?

Comment: @Javastudent See update. Is it clearer?

Comment: If SQLImplicits  has two implicits and both are taking RDD as a parameter, how it'll choose ?

Comment: @Javastudent You should read about implicits in Scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits You can make implicits higher- or lower-priority. Among implicits compiler prefers more specific. If it can't choose you'll have compile error (`ambiguous implicits`). For example https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/SrRDK6FoSCm7mUBxJcQWWw but https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/SrRDK6FoSCm7mUBxJcQWWw/1

Comment: one last thing, import means...we are looking for implicit, makes sense...so the moment we have more methods for existing class after having implicits, how compiler links to these new methods to existing class, I mean does it creates new class with same name with more methods ? Or its just a scala compiler's functionality or style of doing this ?

Comment: @Javastudent Rewriting `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(...).toDF` into `rddToDatasetHolder(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(...)).toDF` is done by compiler